# Onclick not work ie 7 or some Firefox in Facebook App

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, onclick

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="login(); return false;"><img src="images/ie.jpg"/></a>
```

My link isnot fire login(); function. Not work link on ie7 or some firefox .

```
function login(){
FB.login(function(response){
    if(response.authResponse){
    FB.api('/me',function(response){

 window.location.href ="anasayfa.php?fname="+ response.name+"&email="+response.email+"&username="+response.username+"&gender="+response.gender+"&city="+response.hometown.name+"&location="+response.location.name+"&birthday="+response.birthday+"&id="+response.id+"&rStatus="+response.relationship_status;


    });
```

I use these codes on my facebook application. Many users use app. clearly. But some users not use  the app. I tested on ie tester, I see link not work on ie7.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
  href="javascript:;" 

to 

  href="#"
```

See if that corrects your problems in IE. IE7 is very touchy sometimes about hyperlinks.

Comment: if I click button on website , button work normaly. But I click button on facebook iframe , button not work.

Comment: Hmm. and this works in Chrome and other browsers besides IE7? Have you tried this with IE8 or IE9/10? Wondering if it could be a browser centric thing with IE7. Is this site a trusted site in browser security settings?

Comment: Yes it has SSL, and ie8 not work also. you can see normal page, http://yazbahanem.com . On face app, https://www.facebook.com/festivalhali/app_581244431906993?ref=ts   . If you like page, second page opened . The second page, you can see  "DEVAM ET " button. this button not work on ie7/8 with facebook iframe.